# Tomcat versione 8.5.69 and sameSiteCookies=lax doesnt work with saml/onelogin

Tags: java, saml, tomcat8, onelogin, samesite

I have a web application that run on tomcat 8.5.34 and use the single sign on login with saml/onelogin api.
Here the specifications:

- Amazon corretto Jdk 1.8.0_252
- Apache tomcat 8.5.34
- OS Windows 10
- java-saml-2.4.0.jar and java-saml-core-2.4.0.jar

Everithing was fine until we upgrade the tomcat version to 8.5.69, from that version the redirect to our application stopped to work.

Here every attempt to fix the issue:

1. Upgrade the java-saml api --> fail
2. Upgrade the tomcat version till the last 9 release --> fail
3. Change the attribute *classname* in the tag *CookieProcessor* to the *org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcesso*r --> fail

After all we found two solutions:

1. Downgrade the tomcat version (that is not possible in production server, we are migrating to tomcat 9)
2. Change the attribute *sameSiteCookies* in this configuration in context.xml  `<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="lax"/>` from *lax* to *unset*, but this configuration involve my application in a security problem named CSRF attacks so i cant pass VAPT tests.

Now i am in a bottleneck, any suggestions?

Thanks to the all community.